# Overlaying objects onto bootstrap Carousels

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how you overlay a button or other divs over the top of a bootstrap carousel. So far I just have a simple button that does nothing but it gets trapped behind the carousel. I found other fixes that separated the two but I want the button to be positioned over top the carousel. Any help at all would be great!
HTML:

```
<!--Buttons-->
<div id="Buttons" style="z-index: 2;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Buyer</button>
</div>
<!--Carousel-->
<div id="Carousel" class="c-wrapper" style="z-index: 1;">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators overlay">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="Images/Loft1.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="Images/Loft2.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="Images/Loft3.jpg" alt="Flower">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="Images/Loft4.jpg" alt="Flower">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        html,body{overflow:hidden;}
    html,body{height:100%;}
    .carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
    .carousel-inner{height:100%;}

    div.c-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item > img, 
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img{
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding position on button

```
#Buttons{
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
}
```

You can add top and left value also to position this